# ls *CNC* $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -mQ displays all files fron inreject folder - why not only files with CNC in name?

Tags: unix, ls

`ls *CNC* -mQ` is working like it should by displaying only files with CNC but
`ls *CNC* $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -mQ` displays all files from inreject folder - why?

In my script (or rather my colleague who left a while ago and I have modified it a bit) I need to list in email all files which will be deleted for particular department / group of users but command ls *CNC* $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -mQ displays all files (the delete is working fine)

command find $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -type f -name "CNC*" is working fine but displays path to the files and I do not want to send it to users

The script is like below

```
#starting script
echo "Start..."

rval=0

inValueST=`find $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -type f -name "*CNC*" | wc -l`
totValue=$(($inValueST))
#inValueTEST=`ls *CNC* $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -mQ`
#inValueTEST=`ls $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -mQ`
#inValueTEST=`find $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject -type f -name "*CNC*"`

if [ $totValue -gt 0 ]; then 
foo="  RedPrairie 2010 TEST Reject alert"
foo="$foo \n"
foo="$foo \n"

# check how many *CNC* files
if [ $inValueST -gt 0 ]; then
    foo="$foo Rejected  : $inValueST file(s) \n \n $inValueTEST \n \n Files *CNC* are deleted now from Reject folder"
else
    foo="$foo inreject  : $inValueST file(s) \n"
fi  
foo="$foo \n"

echo -e $foo | mail -s "RedPrairie 2010 TEST Reject alert - *CNC* file(s) in Reject folder" myemail@email.co.uk -- -f yoursupport@email.co.uk
fi

# remove old files from outtray
#echo "Removing old log files..."
find /redprairie/comms/test/comms/inreject -type f -name "*CNC*" -mmin +4 -exec rm {} \;

# end script    
echo "$inValueTEST" 
echo "End..."

exit $rval
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ls` command doesn't work the way you seem to think - it doesn't accept a directory name where the previous pattern is to be searched; it rather handles each argument on its own.

To list all *files with CNC in name* *from inreject folder* without *path*, you can do

```
(cd $DCS_COMMSDIR/inreject; ls -mQ *CNC*)
```

Comment: I hope with time I will get better - thanks once again